# Timber/TWIG part of {{post.content}} above, rest below

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber

I need to output let's say the first 100 letters of **{{post.content}}** somewhere above, and then the second part of **{{post.content}}** below.

```
{{post.content.length(100)}}  //to display the first 100 characters
{{post.content.length(-100)}} //to remove the first 100 characters
```

The above does not seem to be working for this. I was wondering if there is a elegant solution for this (maybee built in to Timber like the *".length()"* )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content does not contain `HTML` you just could go with the [`slice`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/slice.html)-filter

```
{{ lipsum | slice(0, 100) }}

-----------------------------------------

{{ lipsum | slice(100) }}
```

*[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/auero4)*

Comment: It will most likely contain html. Is there another option?

Comment: Is it important the `html` stays in there for any reason? Otherwise apply `striptags` first

Comment: Yeah because i want to use it for post.content. And the user will at least be using <h1> <b> <img> etc. TAGs in there. @DarkBee

Comment: I suggest using CSS and [ellipsis](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) then

Comment: That seems to get us quite a bit of a mess for Google searchbots?
There isn't an option in CSS to only show a certain ammount of characters in a div, is there?

Do you know another way - i would assume this has to be doable in Timber / TWIG / PHP somehow, in a more or less neat way.

Comment: If the content contains `html` you could break the markup. What if the content has an opening tag, e.g `<div>` or `<p>`, then you could remove the closing tag or cut an image tag in half.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's nothing built into Timber right now for this. I'd recommend writing a custom class for your post and making these discrete functions:

```
<?php

  class MyPost extends Timber\Post {

    function content_top() {
        //first grab what WP has in the database
        $content = $this->post_content;     

        //do stuff here to get first 100 chars

        //apply WP's filters
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', ($content));
        return $content;
    }

   function content_bottom() {
        //first grab what WP has in the database
        $content = $this->post_content;     

        //do stuff here to get last 100 chars

        //apply WP's filters
        $content = apply_filters('the_content', ($content));
        return $content;
    }
```

Here's [the guide for creating a custom post class](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/extending-timber/)